# I want to ping (icmp) monitor the worker nodes that make up the kubernetes cluster without using the internal IP of the node

Tags: kubernetes, ping

I want to ping (icmp) monitor the worker nodes that make up the kubernetes cluster without using the internal IP of the node.

Since the IP of worker node changes regularly with dhcp, name resolution or
Is there a way to monitor using the name of node?

If there is a way to monitor worker node with zabbix without using IP, please teach me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use --node-ip to assign public ip as kubelet startup options, please check if it works by using `kubectl get no -o wide` after kubelet restart.